# Is there a way to retrieve the message body when the server returns a 500 internal Server Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a routine that submits a SOAP request using HttpWebRequest and WebResponse.  If the SOAP Request fails the server sends back HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error.   When I trap the error I have yet to find a way to view the body of the reply which contains the fault code.

Is there a way to retrieve the message body when the server returns a 500 internal Server Error?

In body of the reply which I am not able to retrieve.

> faultstring xml:lang="en-US" Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.

Comment: Do you control the service, or just the client?

Comment: I control both the server side and the consumer/client side of the service.  The server side throws an exception if a business rule is Violated and that is what I am tring to capture on the consumer/client side of the SOAP call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't time to test this, but a `WebException` will be thrown in this situation.

You can get access to the error response via the `WebException.Response` property.

You will then be able to access information from the respons, e.g. you could try calling `WebException.Response.GetResponseStream()` to get the body of the response.

Comment: Yes this works.  
catch (WebException e) { 
System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()); 
string str = reader.ReadToEnd();

Comment: Note that in some cases, `Response` will be null.